# Get the current iPhone device orientation

Tags: iphone, orientation, device-orientation, uidevice

I want to get the current device orientation (not the application orientation).
I've tried everything and can't get it work.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; 

NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation =%d",[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation );
NSLog(@"[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]; =%d",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] );

[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

On both logs I get no change no matter what the orientation of the device (real device).
I understand that the application orientation doesn't change because the app is portrait only but why the device one doesn't change?

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect you're misunderstanding how notifications work. You need to register a notification handler and call these methods in there.

Comment: Simple example. First search entry in google btw. http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-486957.html

Comment: I don't want the device to notify me when the orientation changed. I only want to know it's orientation when I need it...